# Ruby on Rails app that provides a normal login(email & password) and omniauth with Google without devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth

I'm sure about which models I need to make for this. I know that a one user has N-number of identities. However, all the examples that I've found use devise, I can't use it because my professor said we weren't allowed. So here's what I've got for my session but so far it only works for omniauth with google. Here's my migrate for identities:

```
    class CreateIdentities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :identities do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.string :name
      t.string :oauth
      t.string :password
      t.string :salt
      t.string :email
      t.datetime :oauth_expires_at
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how my session works, but I'm not sure how to make this work for both types of logins:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/users'
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I also want to make sure that if a user exists, and it is the first time the person logs in with google that, the identities table gets updated instead of creating a new row. I'm not sure this is how it is done, I've tried searching, and I've only found one example, otherwise everything seems to use devise.

If anyone could refer me to some example or give me some hints I'd appreciate it, I'm not looking for someone to do this for me or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

At first check your on your controller that the user exits. You can do this by run a query with the email from your omniauth response.

Query like User.find_by_email(params[:email])

if user already in database you can simply autometically logged in and redirect to his dashboard or where you want to redirect.

For normal login process you can follow those steps:

1. Create a hash (base 64 or any hashing algorithm) with your password when create a new user.
2. Next time when when a user request with user name or password you can simple check both username and password hash(same algorithm) exists on your database.
3. If exists user is valid otherwise invalid user.